# how to use Json list in dropdown button in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart

I have this code which works and print the list but when i use it in a dropdown button, it throws the null red screen error while running the app.

```
Future<void> readJson() async {
    final response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/units.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);

    setState(() {
      List jsonList = data["length"] as List;
      print(jsonList);
    });
  }
```

here is how the Json file structure looks like

```
{
    "length" : [

        {

            "name": "Meter",

            "conversion": 1.0,

            "base_unit": true

        },

        {

            "name": "Millimeter",

            "conversion": 1000.0

        },

        {

            "name": "Centimeter",

            "conversion": 100.0

        }
]
}
```

and here is how the dropdown button looks like,

```
Widget customJsonDropDown(String value, void onChange(val)) {
  return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
          child: SizedBox(
              //width: 80,
              height: 50,
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: value,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  onChange(val);
                },
                items: jsonList?.map((item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text(item['name']),
                        value: item['conversion'].toString(),
                      );
                    }).toList() ??
                    [],
                underline: Container(),
                isExpanded: true,
              ))));
}
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the actual error message you are seeing?

Comment: here is the error i am getting,

items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1

Comment: can you show more of the error? what you've provided doesn't state what actual problem the framework is encountering

Comment: "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . \nEither zero or 2 or more
[DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"

Answer (score 0):

What are you sending in as the `value` parameter to `customJsonDropDown`?
The error message is saying either none of the `value` properties of any of the `items` you have passed to the `DropdownButton` match the value set the `DropdownButton` itself, or that more than one do. Can you confirm what `item['conversion'].toString()` evaluates to, and if exactly one of those values matches the `DropdownButton`'s `value`?

EDIT:
Let me try to clarify a bit:

```dart
Widget customJsonDropDown(String value, void onChange(val)) {
  return ...
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: value, // <-- this needs exactly one corresponding DropdownMenuItem, or be null
                onChanged: (val) {
                  onChange(val); // <-- this needs to update the value above to a value that also matches exactly one of the items you set below, or null
                },
                items: jsonList?.map((item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text(item['name']),
                        value: item['conversion'].toString(), // <-- exactly one of these has to match the DropdownButton's value above, if not null
                      );
                    }).toList() ??
                    [],
// ...
```

Comment: i have declared **String? value;** in the beginning of the file. i am storing the updated dropdown value in the String value.

Comment: what I am looking for is that, when someone select the **"name"** in the dropdown, its corresponding value is set to the **value**, so i can use the value in the future.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks for the help bro. all I did is to add **?** to the String deceleration to hold empty values. but the problem is, how can i set the **meter** as default value.

Comment: is there a way to select the **base unit** as a default when the page loads

Comment: can you not just pass that as `value` to `customJsonDropdown`?

Comment: anyway, i have fixed the issue. I am facing one more issue. and that is, when I selected any **name** from dropdown list, is there any way to store that **name** data in a string so I can updated it somewhere else. I mean I have simple string, and I want to updated that string based on what I select from dropdown. if i select **meter**, it should replace the other string and set it as **meter**

Comment: I would think you can do that in `onChanged`

Comment: but if you look at it closely, I am using ['conversion'] as a dropdown value and I am using ['name'] as a text to display, so how can i get the ['name'] value if i am not using it as a value to return.